# checks validity of credit card in python (cs50 pset6)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to using python and wanted to know how I could improve my program. I'm using the Luhn algorithm, the beginning numbers of the credit cards, and the number of digits in the credit card.

```
from cs50 import get_string
import re
import sys

number = get_string("NUMBER: ")
check = []

if (len(number)) not in (13,15,16):
    print("INVALID")
    print(len(number))
    sys.exit(1)

for i in range(len(number)): # for the length of the string,
    if i%2 == (-2+len(number))%2: # if a counter is modulo 1
        digits = str(int(number[i])*2) #obtains the value of the multiplication
        for j in range(len(digits)):
            check.append(int(digits[j]))
    else:
        check.append(int(number[i]))

total = str(sum(check))


if re.search("0$", total):
    if re.search("^3(4|7)", number):
        print("AMEX")
    elif number[0] == str(4):
        print("VISA")
    elif re.search("^5(1|2|3|4|5)", number):
        print("MASTERCARD")
else:
    print("INVALID")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program would benefit from breaking up logic into functions. This also eliminates the global variables involved.

```
if i%2 == (-2+len(number))%2
```

This line is strange and not immediately obvious what it's doing. A reversed iteration would be easier to understand.

```
import re

def luhn_digit(digit,double):
    if double:
        doubled = digit*2
        return doubled-9 if doubled>9 else doubled
    else:
        return digit

def is_valid_luhn(card):
    check_digit = int(card[-1])
    luhn_sum = sum([
        luhn_digit(int(digit),i%2==0)
        for i,digit in enumerate(reversed(card[:-1]))
    ])
    total = check_digit+luhn_sum
    return total%10==0

def is_valid_card(card):
    return (
        len(card) in (13,15,16) and
        is_valid_luhn(card)
    )

def get_card_type(card):
    if not is_valid_card(card):
        return "INVALID"
    if re.search("^3(4|7)", card):
        return "AMEX"
    if card[0] == str(4):
        return "VISA"
    if re.search("^5(1|2|3|4|5)", card):
        return "MASTERCARD"
    return "INVALID"

print(get_card_type(input("NUMBER: ")))
```